# HTML Responsive image sizes

Tags: html

I'm really struggling with this. I'm implementing a responsive gallery (with columns) with responsive images in my very first web project, formatted for lazy loading. After 760px the gallery turns into 2 columns, at 1365px 3 columns, at 1920px or higher 4 columns.

```
<img class="lazyload"
                  src="placeholder.jpg"
                  data-srcset="image-360w.jpg 360w,
                               image-512w.jpg 512w,
                               image-750w.jpg 750w"
                  data-src="image-750w.jpg"
                  sizes="(min-width:761px) 50vw,
                         (min-width:1366px) 33.3vw,
                         (min-width:1921px) 25vw"
                  alt="Description">
```

In "sizes" I set a min-width at where the 2nd columns appears and it works. But the rest, the several min-widths for each column break point, are not working for me, it loads the biggest every time (I'm not using a Retina Display and have tested in Safari, Firefox and Chrome). Maybe I'm completely overlooking something simple, as I'm very new to this. Anyways, I was thinking if it's possible to use the column-count value to calculate what image to load. Something like calc(100vw / column-count) which doesn't work. How can I solve this? Something about min-width and max-width I'm missing? Should I go to scripts?

Comment: what browser you're using?

Comment: I've tried with Chrome, Firefox and Safari. EDIT: all behave the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `<picture>` tag in `HTML`

```
<picture>
   <!-- Full HD Resolution -->
   <source srcset="https://placehold.it/1920x1080" media="(min-width: 1920px)" />
   <!-- Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge -->
   <source srcset="https://placehold.it/1442x2562" media="(min-width: 1442px)" />
   <!-- HiDPI Laptop -->
   <source srcset="https://placehold.it/1440x900" media="(min-width: 1440px)" />
   <!-- Common Resolution -->
   <source srcset="https://placehold.it/1366x768" media="(min-width: 1366px)" />
   <!-- 4:3 (Old CRT monitors) -->
   <source srcset="https://placehold.it/1280x1024" media="(min-width: 1280px)" />
   <!-- iPad Pro -->
   <source srcset="https://placehold.it/1024x1366" media="(min-width: 1024px)" />
   <!-- iPad -->
   <source srcset="https://placehold.it/768x1024" media="(min-width: 768px)" />
   <!-- iPhone 6 Plus -->
   <source srcset="https://placehold.it/414x736" media="(min-width: 414px)" />
   <!-- Google Nexus 5X -->
   <source srcset="https://placehold.it/412x732" media="(min-width: 412px)" />
   <!-- iPhone 6 -->
   <source srcset="https://placehold.it/375x667" media="(min-width: 375px)" />
   <!-- iPhone 5 -->
   <source srcset="https://placehold.it/320x568" media="(min-width: 320px)" />
   <!-- If the browser doesn't support "srcset" attribute, then load the default resolution -->
   <img src="https://placehold.it/1366x768" alt="Background"/>
 </picture>
```

But it's better to make responsive images using `CSS`

```
img {
    background-image: url('path-to-image');
    background-position: 0% 0%;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }
```

Hope this helps.